# How do I get the target URL of a redirect when requesting resources from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I'm working on a cross-browser user-script/extension. I try to get the redirection target of an URL I query from that script.

Now, using Firefox and GreaseMonkey, this is easy because the response object of GM_xmlhttpRequest has a property `finalUrl`.

In Google Chrome GM_xmlhttpRequest is a wrapper around a cross-domain capable XMLHttpRequest and the response object does not know the "real" URL at all.

So, is there a different way to get the redirect target from a user-script/extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the redirection URL, you can parse it using the `google.*` API provided for extensions.

(let's assume the example of [Facebook Desktop Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), where the success URL is `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`). You'll need to add `tabs`and the URL to your permissions - e.g.,:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://facebook.com/connect/*"
]
```

When a user clicks the login/auth button, you need to perform two steps:

#### Step 1

Add a listener to Tab updates that searches all tabs for the success URL:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
    var lis = this; 
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                            if (tabs[i].url.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html") == 0) {
                                var token = tabs[i].url.match(/[\\?&#]auth_token=([^&#])*/i)
                                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(lis);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    });
});
```

#### Step 2

Redirect the user to the OAUTH page:

```
chrome.tabs.create(
    {
    'url': "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=client_id>&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
    }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the headers and get `location` ?

As in

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Thats all i can think about without seeing your code.

Comment: There is only one problem with that: XHR follows all redirects (per specification) and you never get to see the "Location" header.